# Keep focus on combobox after first selection

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a form with comboboxes and textboxes.

If i am using a keyboard key to iterate through the matching items in the list, after the first matching item, the focus gets lost and moves to the next control (textbox) in the form. It works as expected only if the form has no other controls to switch to after first selection.

Comment: Do you have any code in listBox.SelectionChange event?

Comment: @mehrdadsafa yes quite a lot of code checking dependencies and populating other combo boxes based on the selection. Is there anything in particular i should be looking for ?

Comment: maybe code in `SelectionChanged` causing the problem.